# Add 'www.' to URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been rewriting my URLs like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works fine, however I have a subdirectory that is password protected via apache/htaccess. When I navigate to this directory, my browser gets a 401 error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Don't you get a popup dialog which asks you to authenticate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
RewriteEngine off

... Authorisation lines
```

In the .htaccess file containing your authorisation directives.

Comment: This works! You just ended hours of troubleshooting. One small thing though, after I enter a username/pass and log into the directory, .htaccess won't add www. to the url. Is there an easy fix to that?

Comment: @Norse I went through those hours yesterday! You could try putting your redirect inside your protected directories .htaccess file?

Comment: Hooray! Yet another `mod_rewrite + mod_auth` suicide averted!